# p5.js Collision Detection

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I'm trying to use p5.js's p5.collide2D library to execute some actions. I have a main pulsing module that pulses size-wise to music playing in my sketch, and then as it hits certain shapes I have displaying, I want it to reference the different functions I've set up to transform the main module visually.

Currently in this sketch I'm trying to get the Circle2 function to draw when touchX + touchY collides with the maroon circle. I thought I was using the library correctly, but maybe not. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
var circles = [];
var squares = [];
var sizeProportion = 0.2;

//additional shapes
var r = 0;
var velocity = 1;
var fillColor = color(0, 0, 0);
var hit = false;

var startTime;
var waitTime = 3000;

var drawCircles;
var drawSquares;


function preload() {
  sound = loadSound('assets/findingnemoegg.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);


  amplitude = new p5.Amplitude();
  sound.loop();
  sound.play();

  startTime = millis();
}

function draw() {

  background(255);

  // other shapes + information
  r = r + velocity;
  if ((r > 256) || (r < 0)) {
    velocity = velocity * -1;
  }
  noStroke();

  fill(144, 12, 63, r);
  ellipse(100, 100, 80, 80);


  // drawing circles

  circles.push(new Circle1(touchX, touchY));

  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].display();
    if (circles[i].strokeOpacity <= 0) { // Remove if faded out.
      circles.splice(i, 1); // remove
    }
  }

  //collisions

  if (pointTouchcircle2(touchX, 100, 100)) { // <- collision detection
    //call upon Circle2 function and have the main module draw that
  } else {
    //stay the same.
  }

}

//starting circles
function Circle1(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = 0;
  this.age = 0;

  this.fillOpacity = 20
  this.strokeOpacity = 30

  this.display = function() {

    var level = amplitude.getLevel();
    this.age++;

    if (this.age > 500) {
      this.fillOpacity -= 1;
      this.strokeOpacity -= 1;
    }

    var newSize = map(level, 0, 1, 20, 900);
    this.size = this.size + (sizeProportion * (newSize - this.size));

    strokeWeight(10);
    stroke(152, 251, 152, this.strokeOpacity);
    fill(23, 236, 236, this.fillOpacity);


    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size);
  }
}

//maroon circles
function Circle2(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = 0;
  this.age = 0;

  this.fillOpacity = 20
  this.strokeOpacity = 30

  this.display = function() {

    var level = amplitude.getLevel();
    this.age++;

    if (this.age > 500) {
      this.fillOpacity -= 1;
      this.strokeOpacity -= 1;
    }

    var newSize = map(level, 0, 1, 20, 900);
    this.size = this.size + (sizeProportion * (newSize - this.size));

    strokeWeight(10);
    stroke(173, 212, 92, this.strokeOpacity);
    fill(144, 12, 63, this.fillOpacity);


    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size);
  }
}


//collision functions

function pointTouchcircle2(touch, x, y) {
  if (hit = collidePointCircle(touchX,touchY,100,100,50)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does this code do? What exactly did you expect it to do? How are those two things different? Have you tried debugging? Can you post a [mcve] instead of your entire project?

Comment: http://mmengle.com/new_all/

This is the code in action! So that is what it does. I'm trying to use the collision library to make the main module switch colors / shapes depending on the shapes in overlaps with. Let me repost a simplified code snippet.

Edit: simplified code in original post!

Comment: Your posted code does detect the collision of mouse pointer and maroon circle, I just tested it. What's the problem exactly? Maybe you want to use circle-circle collision instead of point-circle collision? It is a little off and I guess that's because you don't have `ellipseMode(CENTER)`

Comment: Also, you pass `50` as the diameter in the collision function but you draw an ellipse of diameter `80`

Comment: Ah that could be where the error is, with the diameter! Let me play around with that. Also I don't believe the collision detection library is referenced in my html, which is where problems could be arising